# How to sync edit mode with responses in xp:repeat

Tags: xpages

Notes-wise, I have a main doc and its responses documents.
XPage-wise, main doc and responses are displayed in the same xp:view, the responses being in a xp:table constructed by a xp:repeat

Each row of the table holds a panel, whose datasource is of course bound to the particular response.

So far, pretty straightforward, isn't it ?

I would like very much to ensure that, at any time, the edit mode of the main doc and the responses are in sync. Something along the lines of :

1. Everything is in read-only mode
2. User switches main doc to edit mode, automagically all responses switch to edit mode too
3. Ditto in reverse : switching main doc to read-only switches responses to read-only

I tried to dynamically compute the "action" attributes of the data sources in the rows, but that does not seem to work.

I'm thinking of somehow having the responses listen to the event "main doc changes mode" and acting accordingly, but I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around how to do it. Specifically, which event would that be ? Then, how to have the responses listen to an event happening somewhere else ?

Any hint appreciated 
thx

edit : back a few days later, if anyone still there.

As per stwissel's suggestion, here be code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view
        xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
        xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
        style="background-color:rgb(217,217,255)">
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView
                var="subdocsNotesView"
                viewName="#{javascript:compositeData.subdocsNotesView}"
                categoryFilter="#{javascript:compositeData.ctnrK}">
            </xp:dominoView>
        </xp:this.data>

        <xp:table>
            <xp:repeat
                id="leRepeat"
                value="#{subdocsNotesView}"
                var="oneDoc">
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:panel id="rowPanel">
                        <xp:this.data>
                            <xp:dominoDocument
                                var="rowData"
                                formName="Person"
                                documentId="#{javascript:oneDoc.getDocument().getUniversalID()}"
                                action="editDocument">
                            </xp:dominoDocument>
                        </xp:this.data>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xp:inputText
                                id="Name"
                                value="#{rowData.Name}"
                                defaultValue="#{javascript:oneDoc.getDocument().getItemValueString('Name')}">
                            </xp:inputText>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:panel>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:repeat>
        </xp:table>
    </xp:view>
```

Comment: Add a simplified code sample, so it's easier to point out what you need to change. Most likely compute the data source mode should do the trick

Comment: Assuming this is a pure XPages application and there's no client piece then I see no need to actually use "response documents".  they're just not needed in XPages IMO.  You say "in sync".  Again in XPages you can do dynamic lookups that you can not do in the client.  So as long as there's a shared key you can get more "relational" and not have to right data from the parent to the children.  So if this is an XPages only app you might want to consider some alternatives.

Comment: @DavidLeedy : maybe, however the topic here is about the edit mode, and that only.

Comment: @stwissel : code added

Answer (score 1):

Surround your repeat control with a **panel**.
Calculate panel's property `readonly` depending on main document's read or edit mode.
Use a boolean viewScope variable "editMode" to memorize the current mode.

```xml
<xp:table>
    <xp:panel readonly="#{ not viewScope.editMode}">
        <xp:repeat ...>
             ...
        </xp:repeat>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:table>
```

Change mode in buttons:

```xml
<xp:button value="Editmode" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="edit" var="mainDocument">
                </xp:changeDocumentMode>
                <xp:executeScript>
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                         viewScope.editMode = true
                    }]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:executeScript>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:button value="Readmode" id="button2">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="readOnly" var="mainDocument">
                </xp:changeDocumentMode>
                <xp:executeScript>
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                         viewScope.editMode = false
                    }]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Even though repeat's dominoDocument has always property `action="editDocument"` repeat documents are in read mode when panel's property `readonly` is true.
If panel's property `readonly` is false then repeat documents are in edit mode.
This way edit mode of main document and repeat documents is in sync.

Comment: Great, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a Managed Bean which implements the Model View Controller (MVC). The Controller Bean in the view scope contains the current Main Doc model and coordinates access to the main doc and its responses. The Main Doc Model would include an array of the Response Doc Model so that the read mode is managed at the Controller while the data is managed in the model.

John Dalsgaard has an excellent presentation on this topic located [here](https://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/DanNotes-MVC.pdf).

I use this approach for both Parent/Child documents and for documents that contain items which are related or synced lists.

Happy coding.

Comment: Are you sure there is no simpler, native approach ?